# Angularjs get data in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i'm writing a blog by AngularJs. i'm new in it.
I'm create a BlogController and BlogData Service. BlogController use BlogData. BlogData use $http and get data from server. 
my controller like this;

```
barbarapp.controller('BlogController', function ($scope, blogData) {
    $scope.blogPosts = blogData.getBlogPosts(0);
});
```

blogData service like this;

```
barbarapp.factory('blogData', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getBlogPosts: function (pageNumber) {
            debugger;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: 'Blog/GetBlogPosts',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { 'pageNumber': pageNumber }
            }).success(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.posts);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

it is works fine. And i'm create a directive for pageniation (directive use a jquery pagination library). pagination directive like this;

```
barbarapp.directive('createPagination', function (blogData, $q) {
    return function (scope, element) {        
        $(element).pagination({
            items: scope.postCount,
            itemsOnPage: scope.itemsOnPage,
            cssStyle: "light-theme",
            onPageClick: function () {
                var posts = blogData.getBlogPosts(this.currentPage);
                scope.blogPosts = posts;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

directive works fine but posts on onPageClick it's undefined. why it is not work?

Comment: the problem could be `this.currentPage`. I don't see where it is

Comment: @baris Where is the code of `onPageClick`???

Comment: I deleted my answer about promises since ganaraj and Khanh TO pointed out that the premise of the answer was actually false, to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @khanh TO; i delete this.CurrentPage and put 2 in here. Also This not work.

Comment: @sza; onPageClick in directive defination

Comment: @Baris: did you trigger the `onPageClick`? (called it somehow)

Comment: Where is `currentPage` defined?

Comment: Yes it  triggered when i'm click page number button. I'm wrote only alert ('hello'); it's works fine.

Comment: @sza; currentPage defined in jQuery pagination library.

Comment: @Baris Do a `console.log(this.currentPage)`, what's the output?

Comment: @sza; i'm insert breakpoint and i watch this.currentPage's value and it has value like this 1, 2, 4...

Comment: After `scope.blogPosts = posts;`; try adding `scope.$apply()`.

Comment: @Mark Rajcok thanks, scope.$apply() works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, scope.$apply() is needed because the jQuery plugin callback runs "outside" Angular.  In other words, the onPageClick() callback happens without Angular knowing, so even though scope.blogPosts is updated, Angular doesn't notice the scope update.

So, the fix is to add `scope.$apply()` after `scope.blogPosts = posts;` to cause Angular to run a digest cycle, which will cause the view to update.